# @client.command() in discord py is not working for me

Tags: python, discord.py

I've got a problem with discord.py bot, `client.event` `on_message` commands work perfectly for me but `client.command()` doesnt work, I've tried reinstalling everything from python to anaconda but it still doesnt work. (and sorry if question and code was messy I'm sort of new to programming and stackoverflow)

code:

```
import discord
import random
import time
from discord.ext import commands
import discord.utils
songs = []
songs_string = """HaB
LionNorth
Stalingrad
"""
i2 = 0
for song_name in songs_string.splitlines():
    songs.insert(i2, song_name)
    i2 += 1

list1 = []

help = '''
все команды должны начинаться с точки 
dsw сюда ругательство,что бы добавить новое ругательство в sw на время сессии бота
time узнать текущее время
sabaton для получения случайной песни Сабатон (иногда может не работать из-за размера файла)
sw чтобы получить случайную ругань
'''

i = 0
string = f'''ПИДОРАС
ПОШЕЛ НАХУЙ
ДА ТЫ УЕБОК
не интересно,пидор
НАЧАЛЬНИК БЛЯТЬ,ЭТОТ ПИДОРАС ОБОСРАЛСЯ
бля ахуительная история
Я ТВОЙ НАЧАЛЬНИК
КТО БУДЕТ СОСАТЬ
ПОШЕЛ НА РАБОТУ
ЧИСТИ ГОВНО
НИХУЯ НЕ МОЖЕШЬ,ПОШЕЛ НАХУЙ
я с этим гондоном сидеть не буду бля
какие нахуй корабли?
'''
quotes_string = """Недостаточно овладеть премудростью, нужно также уметь пользоваться ею.
Тем, кто хочет учиться, часто вредит авторитет тех, кто учит.
Трудно быть хорошим..
"""
for word in string.splitlines():
    list1.insert(i, word)
    i += 1
restr = ["поговорим-по-душам", "флудилка", "⚠правила⚠", "новости"]
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")


@client.command()
async def hi(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Hi!')

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    for channel in member.guild.channels:
        if str(channel) == "welcome":
            await channel.send(f"""Welcome to the server {member.mention}""")
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if str(message.channel) not in restr:
            if message.content == ".sabaton":
                random.seed(time.time())
                randnum = random.randint(0, len(songs) - 1)
                await message.channel.send(file=discord.File(songs[randnum]))
            elif message.content == ".sw":
                random.seed(time.time())
                randnum = random.randint(0, len(list1) - 1)
                await message.channel.send(list1[randnum].upper())
            elif message.content == ".time":
                await message.channel.send(f"Current time is {time.localtime()}")
            elif message.content == ".help":
                await message.channel.send(help)
            if message.content.startswith(".dsw"):
                msg = message.content.split()
                output = ''
                for word in msg[1:]:
                    output += word
                    output += ' '
                await message.channel.send(f"{output} было добавлено в список ругательств на эту сессию")
                list1.append(output)`





client.run("token here")
```

Comment: are you sending '.hi'  to test it? by default, `@command` uses the name of the func. it decorates as the command name.

Comment: yes,i've tried '.hi' and '$hi' heard this worked,tried them both and no result

Answer (score 4):

When using an `on_message` event, you'll need the bot to `process_commands()` if you're planning on using command decorators:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    await client.process_commands(message)
    # rest of your on_message code
```

---

**References:**

- [`on_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message)
- [`Bot.process_commands()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands) - "Without this coroutine, none of the commands will be triggered. If you choose to override the `on_message()` event, then you should invoke this coroutine as well."

Comment: oh shoot man,real big thanks,now everything works fine,guess i've just skipped this part in the docs lol

Comment: No worries - it's never easy to find the first time, but soon it'll stick with you! Good luck with the rest of your bot :^)